# Automate QGIS export (e.g. to mbtiles)

Tags: qgis, export, mbtiles

I'd like to export maps from QGIS to raster mbtiles with different layer content but similar presets like the same area (EXTENT), the same zoom and image settings.

Currently I'm using the export to mbtiles dialog from QGIS but I've to fill the setting manually for each export (e.g. I've to redefine the area to export and so on).

Is it possible to automate the mbtiles export without using the GUI dialog in an automated way e.g. in some sort of script?

Comment: Are you using [this algorithm](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortiles.html#qgiswritevectortiles_mbtiles)? Have you tried "Run as batch process?" Or you can execute the tool once, press Ctrl+Alt+H, copy the python command, and use as start for a python script

Comment: @BERA thanks. That were exactly the pointers I needed. In fact I'm running now
```
import processing
processing.run("qgis:tilesxyzmbtiles", {parameter_dictionary})
```